# Promise Implementation within LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a [Lightning Datatable with row actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example). Clicking on one the row actions need to make an external callout and get values for another function which dispatches an event with those retrieved values. Like this:

```
case GenerateReport:
            this.selectedRow = event.detail.row;
            this.getDataFromAPI(); //Uses apexContinuation for callouts
            this.dispatchDataForReport();
            break;
```

Both the JS functions work well, but not in sync. I've tried searching online for a similar use-case, but everywhere it's unique. How can implement a Promise(or async/await) approach to get the API data prior to calling the `dispatch` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The getDataFromApi method is a promise, so you can do this using the import name you are using for the Apex continuation call. Let's say it's called the same name.

```
getDataFromApi().then((result) => {
    // Then you can call your other method. Not sure what this is returning.
}).catch((error) => {
    // error handling
});
```

The other option is to you an Async function that you can call from your action. I prefer this option if you are using multiple Apex calls.

```
// Change the function name to whatever is more identifying
async rowActionHandler() {
    try {
        // do what you need to do with this.selectedRow
        const continuationResult = await getDataFromApi();
        // Do what you need to do with the result if at all. If you don't need a result just call awati
        // If you have another apex method you can use await again
        const apexResult = await dispatchDataForReport();
    } catch (error) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: Approach #1 worked for me. I appreciate your quick response.